# How to get the confidence intervals of an lda model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, confidence-interval

I have a lda model created from a data frame, `data.lda = lda(cut ~ ., data = data.train)`, and I was wondering if there was a way to get the confidence intervals of the predictor variables using a different command from `confint()` because it doesn't work with the lda class. Or I would have to attempt a longer approach.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408295/confidence-intervals-for-predictions-from-linear-discriminant-analysis